# Discovering REST Webservice's Parameters

Tags: web-services, rest

When trying to work with a poorly documented REST webservice, is it possible to discover or "reverse engineer" it to find a particular method's parameters? I've used Fiddler and can obviously capture parameters that I send over, but I'm looking to determine what parameters this method can take. A bonus if it gives my the object type.

Hopefully this post doesn't get flagged as "hacking." I swear I'm not!

Comment: Do the service provide an autodocumentation tool or technique such as Swagger or HATOEAS ?

Comment: It looks like they're using Swagger.. however it still seems incomplete.

Comment: If correctly configured, Swagger should give you all the needed information. Aside from that, if you have access to the program "binaries" running the service (for example WAR) you could also try to use a decompiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a standard in the same way that there is a standard for SOAP, e.g. WSDL. Every API is going to be different, so discovery is a process of going down a check list of possibilities and then being disappointed that it isn't implemented.

**Metadata**: [Swagger](https://helloreverb.com/developers/swagger), [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and [WADL](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/). No one has to publish meta data, so often they don't.  Sometimes, the metadata is embedded in the respresentation. So when you request, say a book, you get the properties of the book you expect, and maybe some ad hoc, descriptions of endpoint and URLs that describe what you can do with this representation.

**Discovering Endpoints:**
Directory browsing. This probably won't work, unless directory browsing is enabled and the web service technolgy is file based, say, NET asmx.

**OPTIONS** The HTTP verb is supposed to return which verbs this endpoint will accept. It is often disabled or not implemented. Also requires knowing the endpoint in advance.

**HEAD** This would be useful for edge cases like discovering what headers you would get back and possibly what features that implies. For example, if you see Accept-Ranges after a HEAD request, you can do requests in chunks.